# Android quiz app

Tags: android

I am new to programming and I am creating a simple quiz app in Android.. My question is I want to create different categories of Questions. I have used sqlite database.
I have successfully created the 'General Questions' category and here is the code:

```
List<Question> question_list;
int score = 0; 
int qid = 0;
Question currentQ;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    QuizHelper qh = new QuizHelper(this);
    question_list=qh.getAllQuestions();
    currentQ = question_list.get(qid);
    tv_question = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_question);
    rda = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio1);
    rdb = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio2);
    rdc = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio3);
    rdd = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio4);
    rde = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio5);
    btn_next = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    setQuestionView();
    rg = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.RadioGroup1);
    btn_next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
                answerCheck();

        }
    });
}

   public void answerCheck(){
     rda.setChecked(false);
        rdb.setChecked(false);
        rdc.setChecked(false);
        rdd.setChecked(false);
        rde.setChecked(false);

        rda.setClickable(true);
        rdb.setClickable(true);
        rdc.setClickable(true);
        rdd.setClickable(true);
        rde.setClickable(true);

        rg = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.RadioGroup1);
        answer = (RadioButton)findViewById(rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId());

        if(answer != null){
            if(currentQ.getANSWER().equals(answer.getText()))
            {
                score++;
                Log.d("myscore", "" + score );
            }

        }

    if(qid < 5){
    currentQ = question_list.get(qid);
    setQuestionView();
    }       
}

public void setQuestionView(){
    counter.start();
    tv_question.setText(currentQ.getQUESTION());
    rda.setText(currentQ.getOPTA());
    rdb.setText(currentQ.getOPTB());
    rdc.setText(currentQ.getOPTC());
    rdd.setText(currentQ.getOPTD());
    rde.setText(currentQ.getOPTE());
    qid++;
}
```

Now my question is if I want to implement another category should I use other Activity and inherit the class from MainActivity? Databse contains five questions for 1st category and other 5 for second category.. I have used inheritance but app crashes..Can someone please help me in implementing inheritance?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you are going to get the questions from database, **And** number of questions are fixed, one activity is preferable. Just Set the questions you fetch based on category.

Comment: In answerCheck() method qid variable is set for 1st category i.e it will work from qid 0 to qid 4.. Now how to set it for qid 6 to qid 10 ?

Comment: Don't compare qid. Take another variable category_id, and proceed accordingly.

Comment: @Dhruti Thanks..Should I put the code in answerCheck() method ?

Comment: You will need to get selected category in onCreate before you display questions. Get questions from database according to that category_id. Getting?

Comment: yeah... I am trying.. Thanks for the logic :)

Answer (score 0):

No, you should use only one activity.
You can make a generic question layout and inflate it many times according to your category. 
Now just make query like "getQuestionByCategory(categoryId)" and use in your app.